# Python how to iterate through a list and compare lists of strings found within

Tags: python, iteration, nested-lists

If I have a nested list that looks like this:

`bigstringlist = [['rob', 'bob', 'sam', 'angie'], ['jim', 'angie', 'tom', 'sam'], ['sam', 'mary', 'angie', 'sally']]`

How do I iterate through this list and extract a list of names that appear in all the nested lists? i.e.:

```
finallist = ['sam', 'angie']
```

Would this be better accomplished by typecasting this nested list as a set?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
reduce(set.intersection, map(set , bigstringlist))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything, does this work with Python 2.6?

Comment: @Luminous_Path: what do you mean __doesn't seem to do anything__ ? with your data this code will return __set(['angie', 'sam'])__ which you can convert to a list ... ps: "it work in 2.6"

Comment: Nevermind, must have been some kind of syntax error on my part, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A variation on singularity's solution, maybe a little faster:

```
bigstringiter = iter(bigstringlist)
reduce(set.intersection, bigstringiter, set(next(bigstringiter)))
```